# How to make notification resume and not recreate activity?

Tags: android, notifications, oncreate, ondestroy

I thought I had this figured out, but after some debugging on this question: [How to make notification uncancellable/unremovable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857326/how-to-make-notification-uncancellable-unremovable) I just realized my activity is still getting onCreated() and onDestroyed(), in random order.

My manifest for the activity:

```
<activity
        android:name="***.***.***.*****"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I've also tried launchmodes singleTask, singleInstance.

My intent code for the notification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

As you can see, I've tried every flag that seemed like it could be relevant, but no luck...

This gives some unwanted artifacts, like restarting my AlarmManager and firing the alarmmanager start-task every time the notification is clicked. I'd like to avoid this.

Any suggestions?

Edit: I know there are a ton of questions like this, but none of the solutions offered seem to do the trick here... :/

Edit2: By request, here's my class:

```
package ***.***.***;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyClass extends FragmentActivity {


private static String userName;
String password;
private static Boolean LoggedIn = false;
private static Boolean RunningState = false;
private static Boolean OnlineState = false;
private static String LastReportTime;

private static Boolean isVisible = true;
private static Boolean firstStart = true;

private static TextView onlineTextView;
private static TextView reportTimeTextView;
private static TextView runningStatusTextView;
private static TextView userLoggedInTextView;

private static Context context;

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Settings";

public static final String NOTIFICATION_RUNNING_OK = "Reporting Active";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_USER_STOPPED = "Reporting Stopped";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_NO_NETWORK = "No Network Connected";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_NO_CONNECTION = "No Connection To Server";

public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 10;

public static final int LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
public static final int WAKEUP_LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d("MyClass", "Main onCreate() Called");

    loadVariables();

    com.remobjects.sdk.TypeManager.setPackage("com.remobjects.sdk");
    //if (firstStart)
    //{
        Log.d("MyClass", "Main onCreate() firstStart Called");
        if (RunningState && checkConnection())
        {
           // After runLogin(), onResume() gets called here again immediately
            setLoginCode(LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE);
            runLogin();
        }
        else
            init();
    //}
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    Log.d("MyClass", "Main onResume() Called");
    //firstStart gets set to false during login
    if (!firstStart)
    {
        Log.d("MyClass", "Main onResume() !firstStart Called");
        loadVariables();
        setVisible(true);
        updateUI();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    saveVariables();
    setVisible(false);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();

    saveVariables();
    setVisible(false);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    //cancelNotification();
    Log.e("MyClass", "onDestroy() called");
    saveVariables();
    setVisible(false);
    //setFirstStart(true);
}


private void loadVariables()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

    userName = sharedPrefs.getString("userName", "");
    RunningState = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("RunningState", true);
    LoggedIn = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("LoggedIn", false);
    OnlineState = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("OnlineState", false);
    LastReportTime = sharedPrefs.getString("LastReportTime", "");

    context = this.getApplicationContext();
}

private static void saveVariables()
{
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putString("userName", userName);
    editor.putBoolean("RunningState", RunningState);
    editor.putBoolean("LoggedIn", LoggedIn);
    editor.putBoolean("OnlineState", OnlineState);
    editor.putString("LastReportTime", LastReportTime);

    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_my_class, menu);
    return true;
}

private Boolean checkConnection()
{
    Log.d("MyClass", "checkConnection()");
    ConnectivityManager cnnxManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo ni = cnnxManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (ni != null && ni.isAvailable() && ni.isConnected()) 
    {
        OnlineState = true;
        return true;
    }
    OnlineState = false;
    return false;
}

public void runLogin()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, getLoginCode());
    Log.d("MyClass", "runLogin()");
}

private void init()
{
    Log.d("MyClass", "init()");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_field_agent);

    onlineTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.onlineStatusTextView);
    reportTimeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lastReportTimeTextView);
    runningStatusTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.runningStatusTextView);
    userLoggedInTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userLoggedInTextView);

    findViewById(R.id.button_online).getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    findViewById(R.id.button_highRisk).getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFFA500, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    findViewById(R.id.button_alarm).getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    setVisible(true);

    updateUI();

    if (RunningState)
    {
        setupAlarmManager(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES);
        // Here onResume() gets called again
        updateNotificationText(NOTIFICATION_RUNNING_OK);

        Button temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_online);
        temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check_box, 0, R.drawable.check_box, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        //cancelAlarmManager();

        updateNotificationText(NOTIFICATION_USER_STOPPED);

        Button temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_offline);
        temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check_box, 0, R.drawable.check_box, 0);
    }
}

private void updateUI() 
{
    Log.d("MyClass", "updateUI()");

    updateUserLoggedInStatus(userName);

    updateOnlineStatus(OnlineState);

    updateRunningStatus(RunningState);

    updateReportTimeStatus(LastReportTime);
}

public void offDutyButton_click(View view)
{
    cancelAlarmManager();
    Button temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_offline);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check_box, 0, R.drawable.check_box, 0);

    temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_online);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

    temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_highRisk);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

    temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_alarm);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

public void onDutyButton_click(View view)
{
    Button temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_online);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check_box, 0, R.drawable.check_box, 0);

    temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_offline);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

    temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_highRisk);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

    temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_alarm);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //cancelAlarmManager();
    setupAlarmManager(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES);
}

public void highRiskButton_click(View view)
{
    Button temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_highRisk);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check_box, 0, R.drawable.check_box, 0);

    temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_online);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

    temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_offline);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

    temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_alarm);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

public void alarmButton_click(View view)
{
    Button temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_alarm);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check_box, 0, R.drawable.check_box, 0);

    temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_online);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

    temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_highRisk);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

    temp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_offline);
    temp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

public static void setButtonIcon(int inId)
{

}

public static void showToast(String inString, Context context)
{
    Toast.makeText(context, inString.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public static void updateOnlineStatus(Boolean inStatus)
{
    if (isVisible)
    {
        if (inStatus)
            onlineTextView.setText("Online");
        else
            onlineTextView.setText("Offline");
    }
}

public static void updateReportTimeStatus(String inString)
{
    if (isVisible)
        reportTimeTextView.setText(inString);
}

public static void updateRunningStatus(Boolean inStatus)
{
    if (isVisible)
    {
        if (inStatus)
            runningStatusTextView.setText("Reporting");
        else
            runningStatusTextView.setText("Not Reporting");
    }
}

public static void updateUserLoggedInStatus(String inString)
{
    if (isVisible)
        userLoggedInTextView.setText(inString);
}


//
//
// Getters and Setters
//
//
public static void setLoggedIn(Boolean inBool)
{
    LoggedIn = inBool;
}

public static Boolean getLoggedIn()
{
    return LoggedIn;
}

public static void setRunningState(Boolean inBool)
{
    RunningState = inBool;
}

public static Boolean getRunningState()
{
    return RunningState;
}

public static void setVisible(Boolean inBool)
{
    isVisible = inBool;
}

public static Boolean getVisible()
{
    return isVisible;
}

public static void setUsername(String inString)
{
    userName = inString;
}

public static String getUsername()
{
    return userName;
}

public static void setLastReportTime(String inString)
{
    LastReportTime = inString;
}

public static String getLastReportTime()
{
    return LastReportTime;
}

public static Context getAppContext()
{
    return MyClass.context;
}

public static void setLoginCode(int code)
{
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putInt("LoginCode", code);

    editor.commit();
}

public static int getLoginCode()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

    return sharedPrefs.getInt("LoginCode", 1);
}

public static void setFirstStart(Boolean inBool)
{
    firstStart = inBool;
}

public static Boolean getFirstStart()
{
    return firstStart;
}

//
//
//
//
//
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  switch(requestCode) {
    case (LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE) : {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        LoggedIn = data.getBooleanExtra("LoggedIn", false);
        userName = data.getStringExtra("Username");

        init();
      }
      break;
    }
    case (WAKEUP_LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE) : {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          LoggedIn = data.getBooleanExtra("LoggedIn", false);
          userName = data.getStringExtra("Username");

          cancelAlarmManager();
          setupAlarmManager(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES);
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}

//
//
// AlarmManager
//
//

public static void setupAlarmManager(long interval)
{
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, LaunchReceiver.class); 
    PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 0, interval,  pendingAlarmIntent);

    RunningState = true;
    updateRunningStatus(RunningState);

    updateNotificationText(NOTIFICATION_RUNNING_OK);

    Log.d("MyClass", "AlarmManager Started");
}


public static void cancelAlarmManager()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), LaunchReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);

    RunningState = false;
    updateRunningStatus(RunningState);

    updateNotificationText(NOTIFICATION_USER_STOPPED);

    Log.d("MyClass", "AlarmManager Stopped");

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MonitorService.class);
    context.stopService(serviceIntent);
    Log.d("MyClass", "Stopping MonitorService");
}



//
//
// Notification
//
//

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static void createNotification()
{
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setContentTitle("blablabla")
                            .setContentText("Getting Status")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setOngoing(true)
                            .setAutoCancel(false);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyClass.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    /*Notification noti = builder.build();
    noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;*/

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}

public static void updateNotificationText(String inString)
{
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                            .setContentText(inString)
                                            .setContentTitle("blablabla")
                                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                            .setOngoing(true)
                                            .setAutoCancel(false);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyClass.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    /*Notification noti = builder.build();
    noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;*/

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}

public static void cancelNotification()
{
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, after starting the loginActivity, onResume() here gets called again immediately. Same after starting the alarmManager.

Also, every time the alarmManager ticks, it seems to bring the app to the foreground. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: Activities are never created and destroyed in random order. Please post all relevant code. (the code for the class creating the notification, and the class that the notification leads to)

Comment: @Knossos I added the relevant class

Comment: this helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305088/how-to-make-notification-intent-resume-rather-than-making-a-new-intent/39482464#39482464

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Looks like the problem was caused by these lines in the notification-code (taken straight from Android's guide on notifications:

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(FieldAgent.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Replacing them with a regular pendingintent like this solved it:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

An complete example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myactivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

Notification myNotification  = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setContentTitle("Title")
                        .setContentText("Some text....")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.myicon)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true).build();


NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, myNotification);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually tried using `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` and the TaskStackBuilder. What worked in my case is using the `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the PendingIntent

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the answer have by CeeRo worked but in a weird fashion. I HAD TO RESTART THE PHONE! :)

Comment: For me too. Thanks.

Comment: I had similar issue after switching from TaskStackBuilder to `PendingIntent.getActivity()` with the same `requestCode` and `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`. In this case the cached PendingIntent is returned (with wrong flags set earlier by TaskStackBuilder).

Changing `requestCode` or setting `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` ([temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14029400/9316168)) fixes this issue without rebooting the phone.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if my case like you or not.
I tried to create intent as you.
I am using pageviewer + fragment.
My case, click notification message to go app then home to main, then start app again, activity recreated
(this code in class fragment)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Now it's ok, changed to this code:

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
PendingIntent pendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Hope this help ^_^

Comment: Works. Thank you! :)

Comment: It starts a new activity instead of returning to existing

Answer (score 0):

Have you overriden onBackPressed on your Activity? I think if you don't override onBackPressed, Android's default is to destroy (finish()) the Activity. So probably if you are going back then your notification checks whether the Activity already exists, finds none and then creates a new one.

Comment: This happens even if I have the activity open, pull down the notification bar, and click on the notification...

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of code that is being run multiple times.

Remove:

```
saveVariables();
setVisible(false);
```

From onStop() and onDestroy(). This code will always have been run first already in onPause().

loadVariables(); may also be ran twice. Once in onCreate() and once in onResume().

It may be wise to change your loading logic somewhat.

It may be possible that your init() code is being ran twice. Once in onCreate() and once in onActivityResult().

**TL;DR As for your actual problem:**

onActivityResult() is a bit weird sometimes, in that it doesn't always fire when you think it should. Try loading your variables before the init() in onActivityResult().

To experiment with this, place a log in your onCreate(), onStart(), onResume() and onActivityResult() and notice when each is started.

Comment: I'm logging like a madman already :P I've made some small changes, starting and stopping the alarmManager less (I don't think I needed to do that as often as I did). Also removed those from onStop and onDestroy, and for some weird reason, the less code I have in onDestroy, the less it seems to get called. Now it doesn't seem to get called at all when clicking on the notifications (so far at least, i've only clicked it 20-30 times..) ... to be continued

Comment: But clicking the notification still makes the activity restart from onCreate(). The process after that is as I would expect and want it for a fresh start, but this isn't supposed to be a fresh start, it's supposed to be a resume... That's my actual problem ;)

Comment: Actually I was wrong. I clicked notification, and so made a call to onCreate, at: 12:46:31, 12:46:36, 12:46:40, 12:47:55. Then suddenly, at 12:50:07, all the onDestroy's popped up. They don't destroy my current version though, as the next thing in the log after those destroys is onResume(), and even the !firstStart version of it. I'm confused. Any ideas what's causing the notifications to remake the activity?

Comment: When you click on a notification, it will spawn a new instance of the Activity. You could try setting the Activity manifest launch mode to "singleInstance".

Comment: Can't use singleInstance, as I need more activities, services and receivers to run... I need to use singleTop. But I think I finally figured it out. Thanks for trying to help